# How to use the .bimx file in the Android 3D model viewer

Tags: android

How to use the .bimx file in the Android 3D model viewer?

Have seen this view in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.graphisoft.bimx

Comment: https://fileinfo.com/extension/bimx take a look over here